# How to disable touch in flutter on entire screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I found different packages like absorb pointer etc but that is disabling touch on widgets used by my flutter app. but i want to disable touch on entire screen like for example i have a window overlay button on another apps and when pressed that button just disable touch  anywhere on screen

Comment: "but i want to disable touch on entire screen" - use `IgnorePointer` that is a parent to entire `MaterialApp` then

Comment: will this dissable touch out side app also..? like in the top of the screen there is something like appbar that shows time sim card etc info will it disable touh on that place also..?

Comment: It disables all `MaterialApp` components including `appBar: ...`

Comment: what about outside app

Comment: i am using button overlay like mesanger have and when pressed that i want to disable screen touch

Comment: so did you try that `IgnorePointer` ans a parent to `MatetialApp`?

Comment: yes its not working.

Comment: it is working: `runApp(IgnorePointer(child: MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(leading: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => print('app bar pressed'), child: Text('foo')),)),)));` - here you cannot press app bar, if you remove `IgnorePointer` you can do it

Comment: yes but its on appbar actually my goal is that i have a floating window button like messanger app that also appears on anothers app right..? and and imagine if messanger floatting button is on other app and pressed that button the whole screen touch becomes disable even button is on facebook whtaspp anything.. are you getting what i mean

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your widget in AbsorbPointer widget and make the value of the absorbing property true by default.It won't receive touches. To enable the touch again, you can set absorbing: false

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Flutter Disable Touch Example'),
   ),
  body: AbsorbPointer(
    absorbing: true,// it will work even if you don't write
    child: Center(
        child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
           ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('Example 1'),
               onPressed: () {},
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
               child: const Text('Example 2'),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
```

You want look like this?

[image]

Comment: yes but its on appbar actually my goal is that i have a floating window button like messanger app that also appears on anothers app right..? and and imagine if messanger floatting button is on other app and pressed that button the whole screen touch becomes disable even button is on facebook whtaspp anything.. are you getting what i mean

Comment: i want to disable the touch like in the background of this image the wednesday is written suppose this is button or any app i want to make that app or button touch disable